# Uncaught: Type error: this.removeClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a common pagination code, cshtml in the form of a partial view:

```
<div id="paging">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<a data-mini="true" class="action ui-btn" data-bind="css: previousPageEnabled() ? '' : 'ui-disabled'">&lt;</a>
<a data-mini="true" class="action ui-btn" data-bind="css: nextPageEnabled() ? '' : 'ui-disabled'">&lt;</a>
</div>
```

The respective js code for this is:

```
(function($, model){
function injectPaging(viewModel. selector, pageSize){
//Code that does the pagination part
}
}
```

The main view is using jquery: jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js
Through the debugger console, it is giving me error at this line(9408):

```
this.removeClass( "ui-flipswitch-input" );
```

Link to the jquery page: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

Now the issue is, this code is working fine for all the pages as this pagination is used by all the other views that implement pagination and only giving issue for one view. I don't want to change anything in the jQuery file and I am having no clue what might be causing the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per jquery-mobile Github](https://github.com/jquery-archive/jquery-mobile/issues/8071#issuecomment-92968931) instead of concerned line try using this:

```
this.element.removeClass("ui-flipswitch-input");
```

You can try updating the jquery-mobile to 1.5.0-rc1, the bug seems to be fixed there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Bely. As I mentioned above< i don't want to make any changes in the lib file, as for any future upgrades, I would again start getting errors. I did try the above change mentioned by you and it did worked. But I am trying to find what could be wrong with my code or any way I can find out if any exception is being thrown by my code.

Comment: @SumitRoy it looks the error is thrown from the library not from your code, here's the issue https://github.com/jquery-archive/jquery-mobile/issues/8071#issuecomment-92968931. You can try updating the library to 1.5.0-rc1, the bug seems to be fixed there

Comment: Thanks very much @Pavel Bely. Let me update the library and get back on this

Comment: I have recently upgraded my jquery Ui version to 1.13.2. And this issue seems to be happening post this upgrade.  I am wondering if this could have caused the issue.  Also not able to figure out if jquery is saying their latest stable release is 1.4.5, then why they have not release next stable version as 1.5

Comment: @SumitRoy mind that jQuery Ui and jquery-mobile are idffernt libraries. The concerned bug exists in jquery-mobile (https://jquerymobile.com/) that looks like is not actively maintained